# Forbidden error when accessing shiny app embedded in iframe

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have and shiny app deployed on shiny server (open source version).
When I embed the app in a webpage through an iframe I get a "Forbidden,  You don't have permission to access this resource" error.
The app loads perfectly if I put the adress directly in my browser.
The server is local and I'm building and testing my pages through XAMPP.

Comment: You will need to check the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) of your [shiny-server.conf](https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/hdpBcAcPicU).

Comment: Here the [Posit Community crosspost](https://community.rstudio.com/t/forbidden-error-when-embedding-shiny-app/165012/2) can be found.

Comment: my bad. I orginally had https:// in my link and as that was not working I removed the https completely. Once I put back http://  instead of https:// it worked.  Thank you.